# GridvIew Max Width (with dynamic column size)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

I've done a fair bit of research already and everything I see ends up people talking about setting column width in a gridview or trying to apply a class which never works unless you are expanding the width to more than the data inside of it - meaning that it would appear that you cannot simply shrink the size of the rendered table to anything less than the size of the data inside of it.

Given the following GridView Code:

```
<asp:GridView
    ItemStyle-CssClass="Item"
    ID="MainGrid"
    CssClass="DistDataGrid"
    CellPadding="3"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Width="100%"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header"
    RowStyle-CssClass="Item"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="AltItem"
    AllowSorting="True"
    AllowPaging="False"
    DataKeyNames="id">
    ...
```

We see that I am specifically stating that the size of the rendered table should be absolutely the size of the container (in this case, 1800 pixels) yet the rendered table ends up with a width of 2545 pixles due to data it contains.

**Is there not a way to *force* that rendered table to be exactly the width of the container which holds it (max-width) and not expand to the data it contains without specifying the width of individual columns?**

Note that setting the `width: 100%` or `max-width: XXX pixels` does *not* work...

Comment: I know You try with `width:100%`... will be job done with `width:100%; box-sizing:border-box;` (css for grid) ? and, of course, remove `width` from `<asp:GridView ...`

Answer (score 1):

This would likely depend on the type of data you are trying to put in the table, but assuming you're storing text, I got this to work for me using GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Width="800">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="Product ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="Date Created" SortExpression="DateCreated" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" HeaderText="Created By" SortExpression="CreatedBy" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

In this case I just set the "Width" property to a value, not max-width.

You could also try making sure wrapping is enabled for the columns where the data is the biggest:

```
<asp:BoundField>
    <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
```